# In HTML what is the difference between wrapping with a class and having it in the same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and according to bootstrap every element must be wrapped by a row and then column.
Is there a difference between

```
<div class="row">
    <hr class="col" />
</div>
```

Vs

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

The behavior of the above seems to be the same to me but I got a review comment asking me to use the 2nd method

Comment: How can we answer this without knowing what `.column` is supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, It was meant to be col and not column.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the structural reasons for why you might not want to define an `<hr>` as a column element, these two examples would be rendered differently.

Your first example is applying the entire scope of Bootstrap's `.col` to `<hr>`, potentially overriding whatever style attributes are already associated to your ruler.  The second example allows the `<hr>` element to rely on its own styling; nested inside the column.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <hr class="col" />
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <hr  />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that the second, nested, example renders the `<hr>` element with padding to its left and right.